# Thread - safe singelton

Tags: c#, multithreading, lazy-evaluation

I have a class which has 3 static members. Each of static member is not thread-safe singleton.
I need to provide a thread safe implementation for their use.Is it ok?Or I need to provide thread-safe wrapper for each of them? If I should - how can I do it using `Lazy<T>`?

Additional question : `Measure()` and `Do()` of `SingeltonClass1/2/3` are not thread-safe is `func1()` thread-safe?

```
 public class MyLazySingleton
 {
     // static holder for instance, need to use lambda to construct since constructor private
    private static readonly Lazy<MyLazySingleton> _instance
        = new Lazy<MyLazySingleton>(() => new MyLazySingleton());

     // private to prevent direct instantiation.
     private MyLazySingleton()
     {
             s_c1 = SingletonClass1.Instance();
             s_c2 = SingletonClass2.Instance();
             s_c3 = SingletonClass3.Instance();
    }

    // accessor for instance
    public static MyLazySingletonInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }
    public void func1()
    {
        if (s_s1.Measure() || s_c2.Measure())
        {
           c_c3.Do();
        }
    }
       static SingletonClass1 s_c1 = null;
       static SingletonClass1 s_c2 = null;
       static SingletonClass1 s_c3 = null;
}
```

How should I re-implement MyLazySingleton if its constructor should get 2 arguments? `string str` and `int i`

I have asked a follow up question [Thread-safe methods in the singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882177/thread-safe-methods-in-the-singelton-class)

Comment: I edited my answer to include your additional edit/question. Likely if you have additional questions, a new targeted question might be appropriate.

Comment: I didn't notice your _third_ question at the bottom that you edited in. How you intend to provide those arguments would affect the answer. I suggest you create a new question _specifically_ about that. (Are the arguments compile-time constants? Would you update your `MyLazySingletonInstance` to pass them in? Would users somehow specify them? etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's thread-safe as it is.

The default value for `Lazy<T>`'s `LazyThreadSafetyMode` is `ExecutionAndPublication`.

From the MSDN page on the [`new Lazy<T>(Func<T>)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> An instance that is created with this constructor may be used
>   concurrently from multiple threads.
>
> The thread safety mode of a Lazy instance that is initialized with
>   this constructor is LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication.

If you were to use [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792409%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where you could pass a *different* `LazyThreadSafetyMode` value it wouldn't be thread safe. But using the constructor as you are now, it is thread safe.

EDIT: Regarding your additional edited question, if those methods on your `SingletonClass1` type are *not* thread safe: then *no*, `func1` is not thread safe either.

From the [`Lazy<T>` MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Making the Lazy object thread safe does not protect the lazily
>   initialized object. If multiple threads can access the lazily
>   initialized object, you must make its properties and methods safe for
>   multithreaded access.

You will need to make sure that those methods/interactions between those classes are thread safe. This *might* be as simple as wrapping the `func1` body with a `lock` statement, but I can't say for certain depending on how your 3 instances of `SingletonClass1` interact with each other or how calling code may access them.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure Thread-safety you have to set the `LazyThreadSafetyMode` parameter of the `Lazy<T>` constructor. There are 3 available values:

- `None`: not thread-safe
- `PublicationOnly`: many `MyLazySingleton` instance may be created, but only one will be published/returned by the `Value` property. Internally it uses `Interlocked.CompareExchange`
- `ExecutionAndPublication`: The value is create only once

Here's an example:

```
new Lazy<Test>(() => new Test(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
```

Comment: Yakov doesn't need to change the constructor and you don't have to specify thread safety. The default values for `Lazy` make them thread-safe. To ensure thread safety, Yakov _doesn't_ need to set the `LazyThreadSafetyMode` parameter.