# Thread-safe methods in the singleton class

Tags: c#, multithreading

The question is a follow-up to [Thread - safe singelton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880978/thread-safe-singelton?noredirect=1#comment34914849_22880978)

I have a following class :

```
public class MyLazySingleton
{
    // static holder for instance, need to use lambda to construct since constructor private
    private static readonly Lazy<MyLazySingleton> _instance
        = new Lazy<MyLazySingleton>(() => new MyLazySingleton());

    // private to prevent direct instantiation.
    private MyLazySingleton(string str,int i)
    {
             s_c1 = SingletonClass1.Instance(str);
             s_c2 = SingletonClass2.Instance(str);
             s_c3 = SingletonClass3.Instance(i);
    }

    // accessor for instance
    public static MyLazySingletonInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }
    public void func1()
    {
        if (s_s1.Measure() || s_c2.Measure())
        {
           c_c3.Do();
        }
    }
       static SingletonClass1 s_c1 = null;
       static SingletonClass2 s_c2 = null;
       static SingletonClass3 s_c3 = null;
}
```

1. I started to implement it to have a constructor with arguments, but don`t know how to proceed. Any suggestions?
2. I was said in comments of previous question that func1 is not thread-safe.How to make it thread-safe? Is `MyLazySingleton` defined to be Lazy not for thread-safety?

Comment: What are `SingletonClass1`, `SingletonClass2` and `SingletonClass3`? And why are you assigning values from each of them to `SingletonClass1 ` variables? What would you expect to happen if someone called `MyLazySingletonInstance` twice and used different parameters the second time?

Comment: @JonSkeet- They are singleton classes I get from dll.

Comment: @JonSkeet- the question was edited

Comment: @JonSkeet-It should be called only once(just be parameterized).

Comment: @Yakov, have you read JonSkeet's guide to Singletons in C#?  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: "It should only be called once" - then why bother making it a singleton at all?

Comment: I meant I need to initialize it once with given arguments.

Comment: @Yakov: How do you plan on providing the values to those arguments? Do they come from who calls `MyLazySingletonInstance`, or are they essentially constants? If the latter, you can include them in your `Lazy` declaration: `private static readonly Lazy<MyLazySingleton> _instance = new Lazy<MyLazySingleton>(() => new MyLazySingleton("myString", 9000));`

Comment: @Yakov: Regarding thread safety, if nobody else can access your `s_s1`, `s_c2`, and `c_c3` instances, then you can simply add a [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement around the main body of your `func1` method.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - they are not constants

Comment: @Yakov: Then how do you plan on providing them to the `MyLazySingleton` constructor? Where do their values come from?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - from caller

Comment: @Yakov: What caller? Do you intend to change the `MyLazySingletonInstance` property to be a method with those values as inputs? If so, that kind of defeats the purpose of using a singleton (all other users will have to pass in values even if the singleton is already initialized)